# Can I still replicate my loal CouchDB to Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm learning CouchDB and trying out Cloudant as a hosted solution. I'm quite familiar with MongoDB and have used MLab extensively. I wanted to try CouchDB. The tutorial video I'm following shows this Cloudant user-interface:

[image]

I've signed up to IBM Cloud, created a Cloudant service and service credentials and there's no option for CouchDB. It seems the Cloudant website has changed. The www.cloudant.com domain just redirects to IBM now. Is it still possible to get to the interface I've provided in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with specific browsers (Firefox) with tracking protection on, which blocks out the launch button. This is being addressed, but in the mean time, try another browser is the somewhat unsatisfactory answer.

Comment: Yes, I figured out but didn't come back to SO to address this question. I'm on Chrome with the Disconnect extension which blocks out trackers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to IBM bluemix
2. Go to your Dashboard (you should see your cloudant service)
3. Click on your Cloudant service
4. Click on the green launch button

You should be redirected to an url that looks like this: https://{guid}-bluemix.cloudant.com/dashboard.html

From there you will be able to manage your replications.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. So I'm on my Dashboard - https://prnt.sc/kwh3z8. I click my Cloudant service and it leads me to this screen - https://prnt.sc/kwh42r. I created a service credential. I can't find a green launch button anywhere. I'm pretty sure Connections tab isn't what I'm looking for. Would you be able to please clarify where the green launch is?

Comment: The green button is on the manage tab. From my dashboard, it right on the section below your screenshot. I suggest you contact IBM supports.